# TestNG/Junit configure output style in console

Tags: java, junit, testng

When I write and execute test, I feel very distracting to see a lot of noise that TestNG writes on the terminal like this:

```
[testng] ===============================================
[testng]     Mynamespace.Test
[testng]     Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
[testng] ===============================================
[testng]
[testng] THIS:Foo(super=Foo(param=ABC1234567, name=null, param=null), id=-314151617)
[testng] PASSED: testAVeryCoolThing on testConstructor(mynamespace.SomeTest)
lines and lines like this...
```

I was used (not with junit/testng) to have test output like this:

```
.......F....E.................................
..............................................
..............................................
```

So basically for every test passing, write a simple dot (it's passing, I'm happy) and for failures and errors the equivalent letter and then *later* show me only the output from failing tests.
Is this something achievable with TestNG/JUnit?

Comment: I tried with the DotTestListener provided by TestNG. The only problem with that is that for failing tests it prints only an "F".
I wanted to know only if some error/failure happen in my test suite, and have the detail only in that case (with class, method and stacktrace). Is that something achievable with a built in Listener?

Answer (score 1):

Just read the [docs](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging).
You need to override some methods from `TestListenerAdapter`: (taken from the docs):

> Here is a listener that displays a "." for each passed test, a "F" for each failure and a "S" for each skip:

```
public class DotTestListener extends TestListenerAdapter {
  private int m_count = 0;

  @Override
  public void onTestFailure(ITestResult tr) {
    log("F");
  }

  @Override
  public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult tr) {
    log("S");
  }

  @Override
  public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult tr) {
    log(".");
  }

  private void log(String string) {
    System.out.print(string);
    if (++m_count % 40 == 0) {
      System.out.println("");
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: Yes, that's true but when I try to do so, and a test fails, the output is not printed to the shell. Is that normal?